# How to open pdf in web browser using ionic 4?

Tags: typescript, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app ,and using file ,file opener ,file transfer , document viewer to open pdf in mobile devices . Now i want to open pdf in web browser ? Below my code for open pdf ...

```
 // My method for open pdf

  openLocalPdf() {
  let filePath = this.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets';

  if (this.platform.is('android')) {
  let fakeName = Date.now();
  this.file.copyFile(filePath, '5-tools.pdf', this.file.dataDirectory, `${fakeName}.pdf`).then(result => {
    this.fileOpener.open(result.nativeURL, 'application/pdf')
      .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
      .catch(e => console.log('Error opening file', e));
  })
  } else {
  // Use Document viewer for iOS for a better UI
  const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
    title: 'My PDF'
  }
  this.document.viewDocument(`${filePath}/5-tools.pdf`, 
 'application/pdf', options);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use IAB / [InAppBrowser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) for this.

You can use this line of code:

```
this.iab.create("https://www.example.com/some.pdf", '_system', 'location=yes');
```

It's designed to let you open the system browser and other things on devices, but on desktop it will just open the link in a new tab on a browser.

I assume you can look up the `platform` code to detect desktop platform that would need wrapping around this.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution and this work for me:

```
public openPDF() {
  this.iab.create('assets/docs/doc.pdf', '_system', 'location=yes');
}
```

This code simple open your local pdf file on default device browser.
I used https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser capacitor plugin.